# PloneIDE intallation Error

Tags: loops, python-3.x, open-source, plone, plone-4.x

Running buildout. This might take a while...
While:
  Installing ploneide.

An internal error occurred due to a bug in either zc.buildout or in a
recipe being used:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/zc.buildout-2.2.1-py2.7.egg/zc/buildout/buildout.py", line 1942, in main
        getattr(buildout, command)(args)
      File "/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/zc.buildout-2.2.1-py2.7.egg/zc/buildout/buildout.py", line 622, in install
        installed_files = self[part]._call(recipe.install)
      File "/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/zc.buildout-2.2.1-py2.7.egg/zc/buildout/buildout.py", line 1366, in _call
        return f()
      File "/Plone/zinstance/src/collective.recipe.ploneide/collective/recipe/ploneide/__init__.py", line 200, in install
        self.install_developer_manual()
      File "/Plone/zinstance/src/collective.recipe.ploneide/collective/recipe/ploneide/__init__.py", line 107, in install_developer_manual
        res = subprocess.Popen(cmd, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
        errread, errwrite)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1327, in _execute_child
        raise child_exception
    OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Buildout.cfg

```
develop =
    src/collective.ploneide
    src/collective.recipe.ploneide

parts=
    ploneide

[Instance]
[ploneide]
recipe = collective.recipe.ploneide
```

Comment: On that specific line the file ``./bin/buildout`` is expected to be around, can you double check that it is?

Answer (score 1):

ploneide may not be super well maintained at this point - last commit from 2012 https://github.com/collective/collective.ploneide

It would help if you posted your buildout.cfg and mentioned which OS you're using.

Comment: The buildout.cfg you posted must not be everything...e.g. which version of Plone? Is there a reason why you are using develop for those two packages instead of getting them from pypi?